# Information theory and Tsfasman-Manin's problem

Tags: it.information-theory, coding-theory

Yuri Manin recently posted an interesting paper on computability of boundary regions of distance-rate trade-offs for error correction codes.
http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1107/1107.4246v1.pdf

I am curious if information theory provides any clues to this problem in asymptotic coding theory?